# Two UIViewController, one XIB File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Let's say, I have three UIViewController

- UserFormViewContoller
- NewUserFormViewController : UserFormViewController
- UpdateUserFormViewController : UserFormViewController

So, NewUserFormViewController and UpdateUserFormViewController view controller inherit from it's parent to share the basic functionality. The different will be their method, create and update.

The views also have a lot of things in common, almost everything. The different view components between NewUserFormViewController and UpdateUserFormViewController is a button to perform save task (create or update)

**Is it possible to have two UIViewController sharing one XIB file?** Let's say, UserFormViewController.xib and then I do

```
[[NewUserFormViewController alloc] initWithNibName@"UserFormViewController" bundle:nil];
[[UpdateUserFormViewController alloc] initWithNibName@"UserFormViewController" bundle:nil];
```

The other question but important is, **when I edit xib file with Interface Builder, what owner's reference outlets and IBActions is it talking about, NewUserFormViewController or UpdateUserFormViewController?**
(IBActions and Outlets showing when we right click at the Placeholders -> File's Owner)

If that's so, I will just use one XIB file and programmatically add other specific view component (It would be great to have only one XIB file so that I can make some changes at a place but effective on both)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use one XIB for different UIViewController.

Comment: yes, its possible, but are there any specific reason to do that ?

Comment: Thanks, Nuzhat, but please see my second question. That's the real question I'm really confuse

Comment: Thanks to you too, Rohan. The reason provided at the last paragraph of my question. (Easier to update view, maintains and else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "file owner" is just a convention so that XCode can show you the correct `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s in its inspectors. If you create a generic (in OO terms: abstract) `UserFormViewController` (.h, .m, .xib), wire it in IB; then subclass it in two `NewUserFormViewController` and `UpdateUserFormViewController`, they'll inherit their outlets and actions from their parent class without any problem.

Comment: Thanks, Cyrille. With some experiment after reading your answer, kinda found the answer of my question.

Comment: @Cyrille: I have inherited one child controller from parent control but IBOutlets of my parent controller are uninitialized. So, I have suspect-ion in inheritance of xib. So, can you please tell me the reason of uninitialized Outlets.

Comment: Actually child class not loading the xib of parent class. Any reason?

Comment: @Armaan does the child class have its own nib? If so, then you need to re-wire everything.

Comment: Yes child has its own nib. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by re-wire everything

Comment: But why I am getting this error?
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <UIView: 0x7ff070517a80; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6080002326e0>> is associated with <UIViewController: 0x7ff070517780>. Clear this association before associating this view with <IdentificationVC: 0x7ff07040e5a0>.

Answer (score 1):

@Armaan I met the same problem by simply call subclass' alloc init method. I fixed this problem by using initWithNibName: and supply xib file name of parent class.

Comment: This will load the xib of parent but not load the xib of child